# How to add multiple values to a parameter in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

How can I add multiple values (these values are extracted with regex extractor) to a parameter.

I have the following test:
[image]

Using the regex extractor I get the following:

[image]

Now I'm using a BeanShell PreProcessor that contains the following code:

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("articleID_matchNr"));
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++) { //regex counts are 1 based
sampler.addArgument("articleIds", "[" + vars.get("articleID_" + i) + "]");
}
```

Using this will generate the following request:

[image]

This will add multiple parameters with the same name (articleIds) which will cause an error when I'm running the test. The correct form of the parameter should be:

```
articleIds=["148437", "148720"]
```

The number of articleIds is different from a user to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's totally expected as you're adding an argument per match. You need to amend your code as follows to get desired behavior:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("[");
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("articleID_matchNr"));
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    sb.append("\"");
    sb.append(vars.get("articleID_" + i));
    if (i < count) {
        sb.append("\", ");
    }
}
sb.append("\"]");
sampler.addArgument("articleIds", sb.toString());
```

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details and kind of JMeter Beanshell scripting cookbook.